# Multiple String Comparison in Bash

Tags: bash, string

```
    ROOTPATH="/path/here"
    p1 = "file1"
    p2 = "file2"

    for file in `find $ROOTPATH type f`; do
    if [["$file" =~ $p1]]; then
      echo 'got p1'
    elif [["$file" =~ $p2]]; then
      echo 'got p1'
    else

    echo 'got nothing'
```

This fails, and I'm not sure why. Both `$p1` and `$p2` are strings, and so is file.

Im trying to do a comparison on (2) strings, to see if `$p1` or `p2` exist in `$file` on two separate conditions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and a possible copy/paste typo regarding the match for $p2 reporting "got p1"; and the extra surrounding spaces on the p1/p2 assignments

Comment: you might use shellcheck.net as a first-pass through the syntax errors, then include any remaining errors in your Question here

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/22142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing required syntax to use `find`'s "search-by-type" operator:

```
for file in $(find "$ROOTPATH" -type f); do
```

Your assignation of the `p1` and `p2` variables are syntactically incorrect:

```
p1="file1"    # Assigns the value 'file1' to the variable p1
p1 = "file1"  # Attempts to execute `p1` with arguments '=' and 'file1'
```

Also, the two `echo` statements are identical, you might want to alter the second case's `echo` command, depending upon your use case.

Further, the syntax of your `if` statements is flawed; a whitespace character or command separator is required both before and after the `[[` and `]]` tokens.

Comment: It also worth to mention about missed spaces `[["$file"` ...

Comment: Can you elaborate where im missing spaces please

Comment: @johnjones you need spaces as in `[[ "$file" .... ]]`. Though quoting the variable within `[[` is not necessary. Also looping through `find` as mentioned by @DopeGhoti is wrong.

Comment: Try something like this: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for file; do [[ $file == *file1* || $file == *file2* ]] && echo "Got $file"; done' _ {} +`. Another note. `=~` matches regular expression. It matches `f` `i` `l` `e` `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing the syntax

```
ROOTPATH="/path/here"
p1="file1"
p2="file2"

for file in `find $ROOTPATH -type f`; 
do
    if [[ $file =~ $p1 ]]; 
    then
        echo "got p1"
    elif [[ $file =~ $p2 ]]; 
    then
        echo "got p2"
    else
        echo "got nothing"
    fi
done
```

Arrangement

- Removing spaces in variable assignment
- `-type` instead of `type`
- Removed `"` in variable `$file` because of `[[` usage
- Added space (`[[ $file` & `p1 ]]`)
- Adding `fi` & `done` terminations

As commented in comments, please be aware of looping with `find` command.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for the heads up